# Large gaps in data SSRS

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008-r2

I am having an issue in SSRS where my data is showing huge gaps between rows. The dataset is trimmed and has no white spaces. Consume whitespace is also set to true. In the picture below, the row above the top one has an even bigger space between the row.

Any idea what's going on here? [image]

Comment: There has to be one field that makes it expand like that, i would copy and paste each field one by one into a word doc and see where your cursor ends.

Comment: I pasted the first 100 rows from the data into excel and expanded the columns to fit to width and they all look normal. My report its only one header row and one detail row as shown above. Not sure what is causing gaps per every few lines :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to figure out what the issue was:

My report included the Details grouping, even though I only wanted the Parent grouping to display. I believe this made the report show large white space gaps, as those would be detail rows that would otherwise be in the report, if it was not grouped by the first Parent row.

Therefore, I deleted the Details grouping under Row Groups which resolved my issue.